# Get list of maps where value of the map is in the list values

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got another brain teaser. How can I get list of maps where value of the map is in the list of values... Here is the code

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [{'id':1, 'name':'a'}, {'id':2, 'name':'b'}];
  List<String> item = ['a'];

  print(list.where((o)=>item.contains(list['name']))); //<- it needs to print first map in the list
```

From this example I want to print list of `list` maps where 'name' is included in the list of `item`. which means if `item` will have ['a', 'b'] then it prints `[{'id':1, 'name':'a'}, {'id':2, 'name':'b'}]`. if `item` has ['b'] it will print `[{'id':2, 'name':'b'}]`

Comment: `print(list.where((o)=>item.contains(o['name'])));`

Comment: @pskink Damn... I was so close :) Thank you:) Do you want to put it as an answer ?

Comment: your welcome, feel free to write a self answer

Comment: @pskink ahh.. there's no point writing self answer without giving you at least something for it.. Well anyway Thank you again :)